# Static Nestest Class, Static attribute access. Brain Teaser

Tags: java, static, field

can someone please explain me why in this snippet the call to X.Y.Z is equivalent to C.Z?
Calling X.Y.Z means that:
- it access statically class X 
then 
- Attribute Y -of type C- (not class Y) 
then 
- attribute Z in C that leads to output "life is pain".

But why the call X.Y makes access to the attribute and not to the class?
What is the theory behind this?

```
public class A {
    public static class X {
        public static class Y {
            public static String Z = "life is good";
        }
        public static C Y; 
    }

    public static class C {
        public static String Z = "life is pain";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(X.Y.Z);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: It is called "shadowing" when variable `public static C Y` shadows `public static class Y`. So when you call `X.Y.Z` in fact you call `X -> variable Y of type C -> static variable Z of class C`

Comment: this code made me look fool ( took plenty of times to actually understand what's behind the scene ) and yeah @AlexeyA. is right

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing particularly interesting about it, it comes down to the order of precedence in the process of name resolution, as specified by the JLS. The name `X.Y` is ambiguous and one of the two choices must take precedence.

If you are truly interested in the gory details, there is a [whole chapter in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5) on the subject (my guess is, your interest will quickly wane once you realize what a wasp's nest you have opened :)

Answer (score 1):

Static class and static attribute are 2 different things completely. Making the call as you did only refers to class variables. `class Y` is not a variable of `A` while the class member `C Y` is.

Static class is, in fact, like any other class. The only difference is that it has no `.java` file of its own and it's logically related to the containing class. But that's it.
If tomorrow you take `class Y` out of `class A`, nothing would break (assuming you change places where you did something like `A.Y myY = new A.Y();`). On the other hand, the variable `public static C Y;` is a part of `class A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have name collisions, if you allow the java compiler to infer the correct one by using the constructor (e.g. `System.out.println(new X.Y().Z);` it works).

Comment: It's not the JVM; it's the compiler.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good catch. I need more coffee.